# PHP Logic for reward when POST reach 1000 Likes

Tags: php, mysql

I have one android application which use PHP and MySQL as backend. I want give some extra points when user's post get 1000, 2000, 3000 likes and so on. I am storing total likes in table called tbl_post which have column called post_likes. I am new in PHP and so I do not have idea how I can achieve above things. currently I am giving points on every like and its working fine. Let me know if someone can help me for give me good logic for do it with PHP and MySQL.

My Table tbl_post have colum like this

```
id, post_title, image_url, user_id, post_likes
```

Thanks

**More Information:** 
I have like as well unlike system. I can get total likes and if its 1000th like, I can give reward but I do not want give chance to my user to cheat with unlike one time and it will be 999 like then again like and get again reward of 1000 likes. I hope its clear.

Comment: so 1 like = 1 row in tbl_post?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ no, its storing total likes, Thanks

Comment: You could create a separate table that tracks the rewards that have been given. Before a reward is awarded, check that table to see if the user has already received the reward for that tier.

Comment: @Kei I thought for similar but I am confuse in logic of give reward in multiply of 1000. Any sample will be helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a second table along the lines of:

```
tbl_post_reward
    id, post_id, milestone
```

When the post hits the threshold for a reward,

1. Check if a post_reward exists for that post with a milestone that matches the threshold
2. If the post_reward exists, do nothing.
3. If the post_reward does not exist, give the reward, and insert a new record to tbl_post_reward using the post's id, and milestone equal to the threshold the reward is for.

(For example, if the reward is for 1000 likes, you would insert 1000 for milestone).

This would ensure a reward is only awarded once for each milestone.

**Edit: As @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ pointed out, another table is not needed. Below is an better option.**

Instead of creating a table, add a `highest_milestone_rewarded` column.

Whenever a post receives a like,

1. Check if the new `post_likes` modulo 1000 is 0. (This checks if the total likes is a multiple of 1000. If doing the check in PHP, you can use the % operator for modulo. If doing it in MySQL, you can use the [MOD](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mod-function.php) function)
2. If the `post_likes` is greater than `highest_milestone_rewarded`, then give the reward and update the post's `highest_milestone_rewarded`. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I think this will help me for solve my issue, Let me try it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello sir! Sorry but there any idea for get total likes in condition of multiply like 1000,2000,3000 dynamically ? because there no up side limit for it. Thanks

Comment: @Nisha You don't need another table for this. let say you reached 10000 likes so we 100% sure he reached 1k, 2k, 3k milestone

Comment: @Nisha, when a post is liked, perhaps you could check if the post_likes % 1000 = 0. (Basically, a check if the post can be divided by 1000 with no remainders). There would be no up side limit to this.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ, thank you, you're right. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
select id, post_title, user_id 
    , case when coalesce(t2.post_likes, 0) >= 1000 then 'Start of Mileston' else '' end as Milestone
    , coalesce(post_likes, 0)/1000 as No_of_MileStone       
from tbl_post
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but its not fixed till 3000 likes, its unlimited in multiply of 1000. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nisha, this is just a suggestion, feel free to modify or expand

Comment: @Nisha, you can able to determine based on the milestone number, no need of separate table.